# Is it possible to override window.document.location.host?

Tags: javascript, security, browser, client-side

**Use-case** :

- My server is in the domain *www.mywebsite.com*
- In a webpage, I have a JavaScript tag call to a WebService which is in the same domaine
- The JavaScript call is signed and is valid only for a limited time
- The WebService use a session cookie set in the same domain to return the user name
  to the browser
- The risk here is that a malicious site can scrape my page to get the valid WebService call and include it to its page to display the user name on it's pages for phishing purpose

**What I do**

Let say that I want to prevent the hotlinking of this JavaScript :
`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://webservice.mywebsite.com/username.js?ID=SERVICE_ID;ts=1386607643;sig=52f72b1a0fe9158d87d9e4ba4e26a731"/>`

In username.js, I do this check :

`if (document.location.host.match(/[.]mywebsite[.]com$/i) == null) {
    document.location.href="http://www.mywebsite.com/error.html";
} else {
    username = username_obtained_using_the_session_cookie
}`

**My question**
Is it safe ?

Comment: Can you elaborate in code or pseudocode what you are doing exactly? I am not sure I fully understand right now.

Comment: It's possible for a different side to read, modify and load the script, I think. But you can make it harder. In addition to hardcoding it to work only on your domain, I'd minify or pack it (or otherwise obfuscate the code), and set the server to only serve the script if the referrer is your domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible to redefine the `window` object:

```
var window = '123';

alert(window.location);
```

gives `undefined` in the alert.

Or even override the `document` object (your edit to your question):

`var document = { "location" : { "host" : "www.mywebsite.com" } };`

so it now passes your test:

```
if (document.location.host.match(/[.]mywebsite[.]com$/i) == null) { document.location.href="http://www.mywebsite.com/error.html"; } else { username = username_obtained_using_the_session_cookie }
```

A better solution would be if you made your web-service respond to a `POST` rather than a `GET` for your method, then due to the the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) it will not be possible for any remote domain to read the contents of your response containing the username.

You can either execute the `POST` in [plain JavaScript](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp) or you can use [JQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/).

Comment: Thanks. The override works in IE although not in FF and Chrome. Is there any solution to prevent the overriding ?

Comment: I tested successfully with Chrome. Rolling your own checks is not the answer - this is what the SOP is already designed to do.

Comment: One thing that I didn't tell you is that I want also display the username on a sister site www.my-other-website.com using the session cookie set on the domain www.mywebsite.com. This is why using a POST is useless in my case

Comment: Check out CORS: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS - this will allow you to give permission for `other-website.com` to make a POST to `www.mywebsite.com`

Comment: Yes you can do this with a "credentialed request". It might be worth you searching SO or posting another question if you're unsure on how this works.

Comment: @Dinh: If you do ask another question and would like my help, please add a comment here with the question link and I'll take a look (mention @SilverlightFox).